# C# SQlite SQL logic error or missing database\r\nnear \"a\": syntax error

Tags: c#, sqlite

I get an error when I try to run this method:

```
public bool InsertLog(string logMsg, string type)
{
    bool result = false;

    string sql = "INSERT INTO `log`(`logmsg`, `type`) VALUES (?a, ?b)";


    using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(m_dbConnectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (var comm = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            comm.CommandText = sql;
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("?a", logMsg);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("?b", type);
            int res = comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            result = (res == 1);

        }
        conn.Close();
    }
    return result;
}
```

On this database table:

```
CREATE TABLE log (
    id        INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY,
    createdAt DATETIME DEFAULT (datetime('now', 'localtime') ),
    logmsg    TEXT,
    type      VARCHAR
);
```

The error message is `{"SQL logic error or missing database\r\nnear \"a\": syntax error"}` (`System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteExpcetion`). Where is the syntax error in the insert query? I don't see it. Can't I use prepared statements this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quotation marks in `values (?, ?)` are for *positional parameters*, so `?a` is incorrect (you can, however, use something like `?123`). If you want to use *named parameters*, change that to `@a`.

See [Binding Values To Prepared Statements](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html).

Comment: Perfect, in mysql I need to use question marks, so I thought it is okay. I will accept your answer when I can. Thanks.